# Getting sum() of all values in a column of a mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sum

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $miles[] = $row['totalDistance'];
```

}
 Echo $result;I am struggling to get my code to work, I am trying to output the total of all of the values in the 'distance' column of my database.

I get the error notice: "undefined variable: miles"

This is my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT sum(distance) AS totalDistance FROM strava";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $miles[] = $row['totalDistance'];
}
Echo $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: You `Echo $miles;` before defining `$miles`.... so is it really such a big surprise?

Comment: You should also define `$miles` as an array before pushing your `$row['totalDistance']` to it

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to assign a value to `$miles` anywhere. Do you perhaps mean to use `$result` instead?

Comment: I have made your suggested changes and now get "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/test.php on line 23" returned. God. Surely this shouldn't be so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The construct `$miles[] =` is a shortcut for appending a new element to an array `$miles`, but you haven't yet defined `$miles`, therefore `$miles` is undefined at that line of the code.